# Input two matrices which didn't specialize size

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I need to input two matrices with their sizes unfixed, using a blank row to declare the end of inputting each matrix.

For example, input:

```
1 2
3 4
(blank row here, end of input matrix 1)
5 6 7
8 9 10
(blank row here, end of input matrix 2)
```

will get a 2*2 matrix and a 2*3 matrix.

My current idea is to build a matrix large enough (like 1000*1000), then set loops and use `cin` to input each element (the code only shows how I input matrix 1):

```
int matx1[1000][1000];
for (i = 0;i < 1000;i++)
    {
        for (j = 0;j < 1000;j++)
        {
            temp = getchar();
            if (temp == '\n')
            {
                mat1.col = j;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                putchar(temp);
            }
            cin>>matx1[i][j];
        }
        temp = getchar();
        if (temp == '\n')
        {
            mat1.row = i;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            putchar(temp);
        }
    }
```

When I running this on Xcode, error happens, the `putchar()` function will interrupt my input in terminal by printing a number each time I press `Enter`, and the input result is in chaos.

I also tried the following code to avoid use of `putchar()`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        temp = getchar();
        if (temp == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            matx1[i][0] = temp;
        for (j = 1; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            cin >> matx1[i][j];
            if (getchar() == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Still, there are serious problems. The `temp` variable stores `char` and even if I convert it to `int` using ASCII, it works only if the first element of each line is smaller than 10, or the data of the first element of each line will be incorrectly stored.

So, the main question is:

How to switch to a new line to input the same matrix after press `Enter` once and switch to inputting the next matrix after press `Enter` again?

Or to say: how to get the event of `'\n'` without interfering with the original input stream?

Comment: Can you use `std::vector`?

Comment: Better idea: Use `getline` to read line per line, together with `std::istringstream` to read the line number by number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem at hand there is a more or less standard approach. You want to read csv data.

In your case, it is a little bit more difficult, because you do have a special format in your csv data. So first a " " separated list and then a empty line between 2 entries.

Now, how could this to be done?  C++ is an object oriented language with many existing algorithms. You can create define a Proxy class and overwrite the extractor operator. The proxy class, and espcially the extractor, will do all the work.

The extractor, and that is the core of the question is, as said, a little bit more tricky. How can this be done?

In the extractor we will first read a complete line from an `std::istream` using the function `std::getline`. After having the line, we see a `std::string` containing "data-fields", delimited by a space. The `std::string` needs to be split up and the "data-fields"-contents shall be stored.

The process of splitting up strings is also called tokenizing. The "data-fields"-content is also called "token". C++ has a standard function for this purpose: `std::sregex_token_iterator`.

And because we have something that has been designed for such purpose, we should use it.

This thing is an iterator. For iterating over a string, hence sregex. The begin part defines, on what range of input we shall operate, then there is a std::regex for what should be matched / or what should not be matched in the input string. The type of matching strategy is given with last parameter.

```
1 --> give me the stuff that I defined in the regex and
-1 --> give me that what is NOT matched based on the regex.
```

We can use this iterator for storing the tokens in a `std::vector`. The `std::vector` has a range constructor, which takes 2 iterators a parameter, and copies the data between the first iterator and 2nd iterator to the `std::vector`.

The statement

```
std::vector token(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), separator, -1), {});
```

defines a variable "token" of type `std::vector<std::string>`, splits up the `std::string` and puts the tokens into the `std::vector`. For your case we will use `std::transform` to change your strings into integers.

Very simple.

Next step. We want to read from a file. The file conatins also some kind of same data. The same data are rows.

And as for above, we can iterate over similar data. If it is the file input or whatever. For this purpose C++ has the std::istream_iterator. This is a template and as a template parameter it gets the type of data that it should read and, as a constructor parameter, it gets a reference to an input stream. It doesnt't matter, if the input stream is a std::cin, or a std::ifstream or a std::istringstream. The behaviour is identical for all kinds of streams.

And since we do not have files an SO, I use (in the below example) a std::istringstream to store the input csv file. But of course you can open a file, by defining a std::ifstream csvFile(filename). No problem.

We can now read the complete csv-file and split it into tokens and get all data, by simply defining a new variable and use again the range constructor.

```
Matrix matrix1( std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>(testCsv), {} );
```

This very simple one-liner will read the complete csv-file and do all the expected work.

Please note: I am using C++17 and can define the `std::vector` without template argument. The compiler can deduce the argument from the given function parameters. This feature is called CTAD ("class template argument deduction").

Additionally, you can see that I do not use the "end()"-iterator explicitely.

This iterator will be constructed from the empty brace-enclosed initializer list with the correct type, because it will be deduced to be the same as the type of the first argument due to the std::vector constructor requiring that.

Ì hope I could answer your basic question. Please see the full blown C++ example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

std::istringstream testCsv{ R"(1 2
3 4

5 6 7
8 9 10

)" };


// Define Alias for easier Reading
//using Columns = std::vector<std::string>;
using Columns = std::vector<int>;
using Matrix = std::vector<Columns>;
// The delimiter
const std::regex re(" ");

// Proxy for the input Iterator
struct ColumnProxy {
    // Overload extractor. Read a complete line
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ColumnProxy& cp) {

        // Read a line
        cp.columns.clear();
        if (std::string line; std::getline(is, line)) {

            if (!line.empty()) {
                // Split values and copy into resulting vector
                std::transform(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1),
                    std::sregex_token_iterator(),
                    std::back_inserter(cp.columns),
                    [](const std::string & s) {return std::stoi(s); });
            }
            else {
                // Notify the caller. End of matrix
                is.setstate(std::ios::eofbit | std::ios::failbit);
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Type cast operator overload.  Cast the type 'Columns' to std::vector<std::string>
    operator Columns() const { return columns; }
protected:
    // Temporary to hold the read vector
    Columns columns{};
};



int main()
{
    // Define variable matrix with its range constructor. Read complete CSV in this statement, So, one liner
    Matrix matrix1( std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>(testCsv), {} );

    // Reset failbit and eofbit
    testCsv.clear();

    // Read 2nd matrix
    Matrix matrix2(std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>(testCsv), {});

    return 0;

}
```

Again:
What a pity that nobody will read this . . .